# Ignore DBUS method in Vala

Tags: dbus, vala

I have a DBUS server implemented in Vala:

```
[DBus (name = "com.github.Test")]
public class Test.Server {
  public int one() {};
  public int two() {};
  }
}
```

I am seeking for some kind of "annotation" that will hide method "two" from DBUS, because in my (real) situation it has some unserializable attributes and the intention is not to use throught DBUS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Manual/Attributes#DBus_Attribute

You're looking for [DBus (visible = false)] on top of the method.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Was hard to find. Thanks :-)